# UI-Router redirecting to a child not working

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Hi I am trying to have a parent state redirect to a child state.

```
export const states = [
 { name: 'top', url: '/top', redirectTo: 'top.bottom' },
 { name: 'top.bottom', url: '/bottom', component: GenericComponent },
];
```

The transition is successful but the child view is not showing up. What am I doing wrong?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ui-router-angular-redirecto-child

In above example you'll see a redirect with a successful transition but it just says "Loading.."

Answer (score 0):

All that's needed is a component for the parent that has a template `<ui-view></ui-view>`. Otherwise child has no place to render it's view.